# redirect_uri not honored in stackexchange oauth

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid, oauth

In `StackExchange` `OAuth` flow the `redirect_uri` is not honoring it seems. When logging in (say login with `google`) once the authentication is successful we are not being redirected to `redirect_uri` even though the `redirect_uri` is having the same domain as the domain of the application website.